# Whitey, yt and Device Support

Tags: terminal

Been out of the loop for a while now, but recently got a Raspberry Pi 2! It's awesome. However, I installed Whitey and YT (so I can run youtube videos without X running). It all installed fine after some tweaking for omxplayer not mplayer.

But every result is http://www.youtube.com/devicesupport

I can't seem to get any actual results, Epiphany works ok, but I don't want to run X

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because Whitey uses the YouTube API v2 which was deprecated in 2014, and officially put out to pasture on 05/06/15.

Whitey won't work until someone updates it to use the Google YouTube API v3.